# compile driver on linux with make

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, drivers

What does this error message mean? I am trying to run make. It looks like configure is missing. Configure is part of the kernel source?

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/glochild/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.10.0_SOURCE modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/glochild/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.10.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.o
/home/glochild/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.10.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.c:55:6: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  " " __TIME__ " " __DATE__ "\n"
      ^
/home/glochild/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.10.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.c:55:19: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  " " __TIME__ " " __DATE__ "\n"
                   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:264: recipe for target '/home/glochild/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.10.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/glochild/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.10.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.o] Error 1
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/home/glochild/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.10.0_SOURCE' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/glochild/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.10.0_SOURCE] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-19-generic'
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: Fix your makefile to remove `-Werror` or `-Wno-date-time` I suppose.

Comment: That worked. I modified the source to remove the date code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *Makefile* add this to the `CFLAGS` variable

```
-Wno-date-time
```

this will disable the warning, and since warnings are treated as errors because the *Makefile* is passing `-Werror` with the `CFLAGS` the code can't compile.

Comment: But what should be the proper fix for this ?? I mean this warning is added in GCC 4.9 for some good reason ??

Comment: The warning tells you that if you use the `__DATE__`  or `__TIME__` macros, the binary you build will be different depending on the time/day you build it on. That means 2 builds will not result in the exact, 100% similar output file even when you did not change any of the code or anything else(aka. "reproducible build"). You either care about that and agree with gcc 4.9 that this is a sensible warning, and remove all `__DATE__`  and `__TIME__`  macros from your code, or you do not care about that and use the `-Wno-date-time`

Answer (score 4):

I understand this is due to the warning being added to later versions of GCC, which would originally compile with eg -Wall, but now no longer do so due to this additional restriction.

If you cannot fix it using the makefile mods above, I have fixed it in my own driver builds by bracketing just the offending line(s) of source with:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdate-time"
... code with __DATE_ __TIME__
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

which turns the 'new' diagnostic off for the affected lines only.