# Issue while building the kernel for Wilink8 module

Tags: linux, makefile, build, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am trying to integrate the `Wilink8` WiFi  module with the `ZedBoard(Zync series SoC from Xilinx)` and when i tried to compile mine linux- Kernel to create the uImage, I am getting the following error:

```
In file included from drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/main.c:43:0:
drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/version.h:1:39: error: macro "__TIMESTAMP__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]static const char *wlcore_timestamp = __TIMESTAMP__;

drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/main.c:5911:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type 
.sched_scan_stop = wl1271_op_sched_scan_stop,

drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/main.c:5911:2: warning: (near initialization for 'wl1271_ops.sched_scan_stop')
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[5]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/main.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore] Error 2
make[3]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/ti] Error 2
make[2]: *** [drivers/net/wireless] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/net] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

Can you help me to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

You may disable treating this warning as error as desribed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798767/compile-driver-on-linux-with-make) or remove line containing timestamp macro from driver source code.